# Android Json parsing how to get Array

Tags: android, json

I have an JSON something like:

```
{
"store":"usa",
"values":["1","2","3","4"];
}
```

and so I go ahead and get a JSON object for values:

```
JSONObject values = json.getJSONObject("values");
```

So now I have this Json object but methods like getName("X") does not work for this type of JSON. There is no key value for the Array now. Its just Strings oen after another.

I want it to return like

```
String[] listValues = value.getArray();
```

But I don't see anything like this.

Any ideas ?

Thanks !!

Comment: Thats not a valid json. Check it..

Comment: Try using google-gson, its really easy! Look it up

Comment: The `;` at the end of the array needs to go for this to be valid JSON. Is that present in the data or just a typo in the post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
JSONArray a = json.getJSONArray("values");
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
    Log.d("Type", a.getString(i););
}
```

Comment: Yep. The key is to use `getJSONArray` instead of `getJSONObject`. The answer would be improved if you edited it to show how to use `a.getLength()` to allocate the `String[]` and then assign elements (instead of logging).

Comment: Thanks that's what I was looking for ... I is feeling burnt out today !

Answer (score 0):

```
String myJson = "{
"store":"usa",
"values":["1","2","3","4"]
}";

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(myJson);

JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("values");
```